# How can I animate an image with CSS so that it travels linearly and shrinks at the same time?

Tags: css, css-animations

The animation is viewable on my website at [www.surfturkey.net](https://www.surfturkey.net)

The issue is occurring on the 'projects' page.

I am having trouble locating the problem with my CSS animation. I have an image in a CSS grid cell. I want to animate it to an absolute position near the top left corner of my page. Currently, the animation shrinks and travels up and to the right in the wrong direction, then jumps outside the grid cell and travels in the desired direction (up and to the left). I can't figure out how to make it transition smoothly from the starting location to the top left corner. I also have an animation which directly precedes the problem animation, which flies in from the left using a transform function and a rotate function. I have the animations in a class. Here's my HTML and CSS. I am using Sass, but I have formatted the code here into plain CSS.

```css
.logo-box__logo {
  transform       : rotateZ(-40deg);
  transform-style : preserve-3d;
  width           : 30rem;
  height          : 30rem;
  }
.slidein {
  animation : slide-in-from-left 1.5s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
  }
.shrink {
  animation : shrink-to-top 1.5s linear 2s 1 normal forwards;
  }
@keyframes slide-in-from-left {
  from { transform : translateX(-1000px); }
  to   { transform : rotateZ(-40deg);     }
  }
@keyframes shrink-to-top {
  from {
    height   : 30rem;
    width    : 30rem;
    position : relative;
  }
  to {
    height   : 10rem;
    width    : 10rem;
    position : absolute;
    top      : 2%;
    left     : 2%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="logo-box">
  <a href="index.html">
    <img class="logo-box__logo shrink" 
      src="https://surfturkey.net/assets/img/surfturkey_right.png" 
      alt="A turkey on a surfboard">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand why is there a grid in `logo-box`. Nevertheless, take a look at this:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;

  
}

html {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  color: #A5C9CA;
  background-color: #395B64;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: -webkit-min-content 20vh 70vh 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 20vh 70vh 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.navbar__links {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 3rem;
}
.navbar__item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #A5C9CA;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: color 1s;
}
.navbar__item:hover {
  color: #C84B31;
}

.slidein {
  -webkit-animation: slide-in-from-left 1.5s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
          animation: slide-in-from-left 1.5s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

.shrinkup {
  -webkit-animation: shrink-to-top 1.5s linear 2s 1 normal forwards;
          animation: shrink-to-top 1.5s linear 2s 1 normal forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in-from-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0) rotateZ(-32deg);
    /* margin-left: 5rem; */
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in-from-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0) rotateZ(-32deg);
    /* margin-left: 5rem; */
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes shrink-to-top {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(-32deg);
  }
  to {
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 2rem;
    transform: rotateZ(-32deg);
  }
}
@keyframes shrink-to-top {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(-32deg);
  }
  to {
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 2rem;
    left: 2rem; */
    transform: rotateZ(-32deg);
  }
}
.main-content {
  grid-row: 4/5;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background-color: #A5C9CA;
  width: 100vw;
}

.accent-font {
  color: #C84B31;
}

.heading {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: -12rem;
}
.heading__title {
  font-size: 14rem;
  text-align: right;
}
.heading__title a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.heading__subtitle {
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.logo-box {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 3/4;
}

.logo-box__logo {
  width: 80rem;
  height: 80rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5rem;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  transform: rotateZ(-32deg);
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<body class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__links">
            <a class="navbar__item" href="#">Our Story</a>
            <a class="navbar__item" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            <a class="navbar__item" href="#">Contact us</a>
            <a class="navbar__item" href="#">Blog</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="logo-box">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img class="logo-box__logo shrinkup" src="https://www.surfturkey.net/assets/img/surfturkey_right.png" alt="A turkey on a surfboard">
        </a>
    </div>

    <header class="heading">
        <h1 class="heading__title">Come <a href="#projects"><span class="accent-font">see</span></a></h1>
        <h2 class="heading__subtitle">what all we're up to...</h2>
    </header>
    
    <main id="projects" class="main-content">
       
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: That solved the jumping glitch. The image however is now shrinking down to the grid cell's top/left. I set all the parent containers to absolute and the body to relative, but it still won't leave the grid cell. A grid-column property won't work inside a keyframe declaration.

Comment: @surfturkey the landing location is top left corner. so what is the start location?

Comment: Starting location is left: 0 with a bit of margin-left to compensate for the tilt.

Comment: The styles got a little hectic so I just scrapped it and created a better layout. I think it is better now. https://www.surfturkey.net

Comment: do you want it to shrink in the spot first then move to top left corner or shrink and move in the same time?

Comment: I'd like to do it at the same time, but even with my new layout it's still a little jerky.

Comment: @surfturkey I updated my answer. is this the result you want?

Comment: Thanks Mad7Dragon for your assistance with this. You get the kudos :)

Comment: glad I helped. keep up the good work.

Comment: Pro tips: (1) for every answer, if you can add an explanation of why your solution works, that may help more readers; (2) it is generally better to refrain from adding answer notes about what you don't understand, since they aren't useful to anyone but the question author. Answers are generally to be addressed to all future readers, rather than just the question author (though it is a nice side-effect if they are helped as well).